# ASP.NET MVC Razor @model syntax error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, syntax-error, razor

This is a syntax question that I can't figure out because I am new to MVC and the razor view engine. I've wrote a directive in a view with a master layout. The directive is @model Demo.ViewModels.Shared.Grid and asp.net is expecting a ";" somewhere. Consequently, I getting an invalid expression and the view isn't call my class properly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It may be helpful to paste the code, or some version of it...

Comment: We would have to see more of the code for the View. The first list of my RazorView is: @model KB.Web.ViewModels.Deal

Comment: Can you give some example code? If you declare the @model on top of the page there shouldn't be any problem.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't share much information about your problem, however your question can still be answered.

Many times, new MVC users write `@{ }` instead of `@()`. The  `@{}` is a code block, so each line of code within the block must end with a semicolon `;`, like regular C# code. Whereas `@()` renders to the response the result of the code, and doesn't require anything contained in it to end with a semicolon `;`.

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to point out that in VB the directive is `@ModelType` vs the directive in C# of `@model`